Darboux integral proof (lower and upper integral)
I have to show how $ \underline{I}_D(f) = -\overline{I}_D(-f) $
( where $ \underline{I}_D(f) $ is the Darboux lower integral of the function $ f $ over the set $D $, and $ \overline{I}_D(f) $ is the Darboux upper integral).
So, in my opinion, this equation is correct:
$$
M_{ij}(-f) = \sup\{-f(P) \mid P \in D_{ij}\} = -\inf\{f(P) \mid P \in D_{ij}\} = -m_{ij}(f),
$$
so $ M_{ij}(-f) = -m_{ij}(f) $, therefore $ -M_{ij}(-f) = m_{ij}(f) $, which means that:
$$
\underline{I}_D(f) = \sup\{s(T, f) \mid T \text{ is a partition of the rectangle } D\} 
= $$
$$
=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n m_{ij}(f) \, \Delta x_i \, \Delta y_j\right\}
= \sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n -M_{ij}(f) \, \Delta x_i \, \Delta y_j\right\}
= \ldots ??? \ldots 
=
$$
$$
=-\inf\left\{\sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^n M_{ij}(-f) \, \Delta x_i \, \Delta y_j\right\}
= -\inf\{S(T, -f) \mid T \text{ is a partition of the rectangle } D\} 
= -\overline{I}_D(-f).
$$

Everything you wrote is correct. I'm guessing you don't know how to argue that $$\sup(-A) =-\inf(A)$$
This follows from the definition of supremum and infimum. Let $a=\sup(-A)$, then, for every $x\in A$ we know $-x\leq a$, which implies $x\geq -a$, this implies that $-a$ is a lower bound for $A$, we only need to prove that it's the largest lower bound. Suppose now $b>-a$, we then have $-b<a$ therefore, since $a$ is the smallest upper bound for $-A$, there exists $x\in A$ such that $-b<-x$ and so $b>x$ and so $b$ is not a lower bound for $A$. This implies that $-a$ is the largest lower bound for $A$. Recalling the definition of $a$ we get
$$\inf A=-a= -\sup(-A)$$
as we wanted

But why does f become −f?

@PKaru you just forgot a - in your calculations. $m_{ij}(f)=-M_{ij}(-f)$

Thank you so much!

@PKaru No problem! Glad to help
